'Bulk, high-ish purity carbon' sources in a mostly contemporary-adjacent setting
Basically what it says on the tin. A society mostly like ours as far as it's technological base goes recently discovers a way to synthesise very useful 'crystals' with carbon, with applications in a wide array of fields. Demand to scale up production spikes, and industry is desperately searching for any sources of cheap carbon of a reasonable purity to work with. Where might they get it?
A/N; a current 'solution' I had in mind involves repurposing hydrocarbon extraction to this purpose, which the discovery of cheap alternative energy sources have made less relevant for that sector. Would extracting carbon from oil / coal be 'possible'?

??? 'Bulk, high-ish purity carbon' is called coal. Preferably anthracite, with 86% to 97% carbon. Costs about 100 dollars per ton. "Total production [of anthracite] in 2020 was 615 million tons" says Wikipedia.

Crystalized carbon is called "diamond" and is already widely produced for a variety of industrial purposes.

If you relax the "crystals" requirement (diamond already covering pretty much anything that being obviously crystalline is a specific advantage for), you're basically describing plastics.

@Cadence: Carbon has two crystalline allotropes: diamond, which is expensive, and graphite, which is not. In 2022, 1.3 million tonnes of graphite were produced and used in pencils, lubricants, electrodes, and other such ordinary applications.

@AlexP there's also lonsdaleite, "hexagonal diamond".

I found this question in the VTC review queue. I don't think it deserves to be closed. The question is a bit flippant, but it's fairly clear and not lacking details. It is lacking research (which is expected before posting on Stack Exchange), so the down votes are deserved.

Carbon is the fourth most common element in the universe, the third which is chemically reactive (helium being inert), and is an extremely common element on Earth's surface, being the second most abundant element in the human body. Soot, coal, charcoal, graphite, etc are all mostly carbon. Most organic materials can be reduced to carbon by heating them, and the pharmaceuticals, plastics, food, agricultural, and petroleum industries specialize in providing those at various levels of purity.
In short, obtaining carbon is not going to be the slightest bit of a challenge. It's not really going to be a constraint anyone brings up, unless you're talking about a moon colony or something where it has to be imported, because obtaining it will just be a matter of ordering it.
As mentioned in comments, there's only a few crystal structures that are actually possible, so you're going to need something more than just "new carbon crystals". Perhaps what you need for these "crystals" is isotopically pure carbon, pure C-12 or C-13 (natural carbon on Earth is about 99:1 ratio of these, with traces of C-14). Isotopically pure diamond is something that has actually been produced for various niche purposes, if it's a prerequisite for whatever special you're doing with the crystals, it would explain why you can't just buy a jar of graphite powder off Amazon or eBay as a precursor.
